# Algorithm to compute prime factors of n from whether x is a square?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Suppose there exists an algorithm that takes input $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$ and returns the square root of $x$ if $x$ is a perfect square and nothing otherwise.

Use this algorithm to compute the prime factors of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, with the added condition that $n = pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes.

I believe this may have something to do with Fermat's factorization method, but I am stuck on how exactly to approach this.

Comment: is there any restriction to what else you're allowed to use?

Comment: No, just have to use the assumed algorithm to somehow make computing prime factors easier.

Comment: I don't think such algorithm 'really helps' at all. Since this algorithm >does< exist. To give a simple answer: 1)use the given algorithm on n, if it doesn't work just do the simple factorization by trying all numbers smaller than n...

Comment: There is an important condition I neglected to type in the original question that should alter the question.

Comment: in that case it's simple, you can just use the algorithm given on wikipedia when you search for fermat's factorization!

Comment: Fermat's factorization is efficient if the prime factors are "almost" equal. But first of all, you need the truncated square root, even if the given number is not a square. So, the described algorithm will not help much.

Comment: "returns the square root of x" is it supposed to return all square roots or just one? 4 has the four roots $\pm 2, \pm 7$. When you can calucate all those you get the factorization because $2^2\equiv7^2 \mod 15$ and $\gcd(7-2, 15) = 5$

Comment: I think it can be assumed that the algorithm returns all square roots.

Comment: So something like $$\sqrt{n} \delta_0^{\sqrt{n} - \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}$$ (yeah, the Kronecker delta, if you don't object to using it on non-integers).